# How to group and limit on count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am building a Rails 3.2 app and in this app I got two tables (postgres).
One called Users and one called Messages.

In the messages table I got a column called user_id. I need to be able to
get how many messages each user have made and present them in a list AND I only what to get those that have made more than 100 messages. If this could be done in one call it would be perfect.

This is my code so far and it works to get how many messages that each user has made but I need to only get those with more than 100 messages.

```
@messages = Message.group("user_id").order("count_all DESC").count
```

Comment: The SQL for this would be `SELECT user_id, count(message.message_id) FROM user INNER JOIN message ON  (user.user_id = message.user_id) GROUP BY user.user_id HAVING count(message.message_id) > 100` . You'd use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of` INNER JOIN` and omit the `HAVING` clause if you wanted to include all users including those with no messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
@messages = Message.count(:all, :group => 'user_id, HAVING COUNT(*) > 100')
```

Or

```
@messages = Message.group('user_id').having('COUNT(*) > 100').count
```

Comment: @JonathanClark It shouldn't be particularly. If it is, get the SQL from Rails and execute it manually in `psql` using `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to get the query plan, then post a follow up question with the SQL, plan, sample data, and a link back to this one. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info